# C# Default optional parameter chooser

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, constructor, optional-parameters

```
    public ClassType(string type) {
        Type = type;
    }
    public ClassType(string type,bool isArray=false) {
        Type = type;
        IsArray = isArray;
    }


    ClassType ct = new ClassType("adsf");
```

Which constructor is chosen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload that doesn't require an optional parameter. Note that it's just a "yes" or "no" decision here: "no optional parameters filled in automatically" is preferable to "some optional parameters filled in automatically" but there's no preference between 1 or 2 being filled in. (That would be ambiguous.)

From section 7.5.3.2 of the C# 4 spec:

> Otherwise if all parameters of M<sub>P</sub> have
>   a corresponding argument whereas
>   default arguments need to be
>   substituted for at least one optional
>   parameter in M<sub>Q</sub> then M<sub>P</sub> is better than
>   M<sub>Q</sub>.

Comment: Which raises the question, "Why isn't that a compile time error?" (I'm pretty sure it is in C++, and C# gives errors for a lot more edge cases that C++ lets by.)

Comment: @James: There's a method which exactly matches the arguments you've given, so I guess it's deemed to be fine. I suspect it makes it easier to add optional parameters to existing types.

Comment: BTW: I've just ported that code to VC++ and confirmed that with that compiler at least, it is an error. I think the C++98 Standard makes it always an error.  Odd that C# lets it pass.  I guess it's to allow you to turn previously required parameters into optional params, but in that case you'd really want to know if you created an ambigity.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon said, in two words, the first one. The match is 'cleaner'.

Comment: Isn't "the first one" three words, not two? ;)